# React Select - Keep the text typed by user in the text field even if user clicks outside the div

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I have trying to keep the Strings typed by the user in the text field so that they can return later to edit it and choose their options from the given react-select dropdown
**My Code**

I have tried this code but if the user clicks twice on this component the text can't be edited anymore and becomes a placeholder value

```
export default function TagInputSearch(props){
const [menuIsOpen, setMenuIsOpen] = useState(false)
const [input, setInput] = useState("");
const [inputSave, setSave] = useState("");

return (
 <div className="tag-input-search">
  <div style={{ display: 'inline-block' }} onClick={() => {(setMenuIsOpen(!menuIsOpen)) }}>
    <SVGIcon name='inputAddButton' width='1rem' height='1rem' />
  </div>
  <div className='small-text-regular' style={{ width: '100%', borderBottom: '1px solid var(--element-dullgrey)' }}>
  <Select
      
      closeMenuOnSelect={true}
      components={{
      MultiValueRemove, DropdownIndicator: () => null,
        IndicatorSeparator: () => null, ClearIndicator: () => null
      }}
      styles={colourStyles}
      isMulti       
      placeholder={inputSave || 'Select Stack'}
      inputValue={input}
      options={props.stackVersionList ? props.stackVersionList : []}
      onChange={(value) =>{
        props.handleStackSelected(value)
      } }
      onFocus={() => {
        setInput(inputSave); 
        setSave("");
      }}
      clearOnBlur = {false}
      onInputChange = {setInput}
      isDisabled={props.isDisabled || false}
      menuIsOpen={menuIsOpen}
      clearOnSelect = {false}
      onMenuOpen={() => {
        setMenuIsOpen(true);
      }}
      onMenuClose={() => {
        setSave(input);
        setMenuIsOpen(false);
      }}
    />
  </div>
</div>
);}
```